# Return JSON to Proxy with WSO2 ESB

Tags: json, proxy, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I'm new in WSO2 esb and for beginning i want to make a http connection to my external REST API and return the JSON response.
To call the proxy i'm using Postman and the request has success, but the json result doesn't show in postman, only in Log.
Then i have added a send mediators but generates exception as below:

```
ERROR - NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.addToBB(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:210)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.commit(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:202)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:765)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:173)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.sendHeaders(Response.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close(OutputBuffer.java:283)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.close(CoyoteOutputStream.java:108)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.sendUsingOutputStream(PassThroughHttpSender.java:298)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:163)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:321)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:94)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:268)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:488)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:170)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

This is my proxy code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Proxy" transports="http https" startOnLoad="true" trace="enable">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <property name="uri.var.name" value="Luca" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint key="HelloWorld"/>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="content" expression="json-eval($.)"/>
            </log>
            <send description=""/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

What do i doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

looks wrong configuration.
Use as follows;
`<send/>` in outsequence and if you want to send json response back to client, set the messageType property too at outsequence.
Eg:

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
```

Eg:

```
<outSequence>
  <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
      <send/>
 </outSequence>
```

Comment: thanks, but also with this property i have the same error:
[2015-03-12 09:34:48,789]  INFO - LogMediator content = {"id":3,"content":"Hello, Luca!"}
[2015-03-12 09:34:48,791] ERROR - NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.addToBB(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:210)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.commit(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:202)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:765)
 ...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're hitting the right port of the service.
If you're went through 'try service' link and copied it to your tool - then you're hitting the wrong port and it WILL result in NullPointerException. Click on  the service name == you should see 'Service Dashboard(Proxy)' page. Then in the section 'Endpoints' there will be list of urls of your service's endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this issue happens when the client use Servlet Transport Port (9443 by default) instead of Pass-through transport port(8243 by default). Check whether you are using the correct port to access the service. Service calls should go through the Pass-through Transport in ESB.